# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Hello i am new to laravel but i can't discover why i can't acess to my default path

My route:

```
      Route::get('/', 'HomeController@home');
```

My controller:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 class HomeController extends Controller
 {

 public function home()
 {
    return view('home.home');
 }
}
```

My route list

[image]

I have try with diferent middlewares and also i have change this api.route
i have delete this:

```
 //Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
  //  return $request->user();
  //});
```

Please help i am start going crazy.

Comment: Do you have a this file `resources/views/home/home.blade.php`?

Comment: yes i have that file

Comment: Can you try and clear your cache with `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: i have try that! not working

Answer (score 27):

Solved my same problem just with command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 10):

in my case:

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize:clear
```

solve the problem

Answer (score 7):

It works for me

```
 php artisan optimize:clear
 php artisan route:clear
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're facing this problem, simply run this command

```
php artisan optimize
```

The above command will clear all routes, files and configurations and also go ahead to create new cache for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache  
php artisan config:cache  
php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: can you bring the home.blade.php content and full error message in question?

Comment: can you tell me how can i run these commands on plex server?

Comment: what is this? replyer

Answer (score 0):

in my case i solve this issue with run : **php artisan cache:clear** command 4 times.

- **more usefull command :**
- php artisan cache:clear # for clear your application cache.
- php artisan route:cache # for clear your application route cache.
- php artisan config:cache # you should cache all of your configuration files into a single file
- php artisan view:clear # if you want to
  clear view cache

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize:clear
```

It works for me

Answer (score -1):

the best way for solving this problem is to clear route cache through

```
php artisan route:clear
```

I have tried many methods but did not get to the right solution however did not lose the heart and try `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score -1):

You can use following commands-

```
php artisan route:clear
```

or

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: How is this answer different from previous answers?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34198599)