# Deleting a user as admin in Laravel 10: "GET method not supported"

Tags: php, laravel, routes, httprequest

I'm building an admin panel in Laravel 10 where the admin can see a listing of all the users along with a link to delete each individual user. When I click on the delete link i'm getting this error: "The GET method is not supported for route admin/users/2. Supported methods: DELETE."
I know it's a very common error but I think I've double checked everything.

Here are my routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'isadmin']], function () {
    Route::get('/admin/dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'adminDashboard'])
        ->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::delete('/admin/users/{user}', [AdminController::class, 'destroyUser'])
        ->name('admin.users.destroy');
    Route::redirect('/admin', '/admin/dashboard');
});
```

My controller:

```
    public function destroyUser(User $user)
    {
        // dd($user);
        $user->delete;

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

My view:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user) }}"
  method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
  <a class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700" href="{{ route('admin.users.destroy', $user) }}">Delete</a>
</form>
```

As you can see, I didn't forget to add `@method('DELETE')` in the form, I've specified the route method as delete in the router. I tried using a submit type button instead of a link. I tried moving the route outside of the middleware. I also tried clearing the cache multiple times.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this helpful?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72456043/10245455

Comment: Also, you missed the parentheses after calling `delete` method on the user object in your controller.

Comment: Good catch! It was causing another issue where the page would simply reload and nothing else happened if I clicked on the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is using a link as a submit button. It needs to be a `button` with the `type` set to `submit`.

```
<button type="submit" class="text-blue-500 hover:text-blue-700"">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Button doesn't accept href attribute. "Submit" button will be correctly interpreted by form itself.

Comment: I'm a dumbass. Thanks for you help! Now I'm getting an integrity constraint violation but that's another issue altogether. Thanks a lot!